# How to solve this transcendental inequality?

Tags: inequality

How can one solve the transcendental inequality

$$ 5^3\times 3^6 > n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)3^n $$

for integers $n\ge5$?

Thank You.

Comment: Begging for help using six exclamation points won't help, and will only hurt, your chances on getting an answer.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you getting stuck? $n$ is an integer or a non-negative integer or a positive integer, or perhaps a real?

Comment: Your interpretation in editing, @gt6989b was way off base here.

Comment: n is positive integer and n >=5

Comment: @amWhy you are right, i thought `5^3x3^6` wasa typo. This inequality is blatantly false otherwise, for any decent size $n$

Comment: @zuser1837636362 did you try to plug in $n=7$, for example?

Comment: No problem, @gt6989b.  I know you were only trying to help clarify things.

Comment: n=5 is one answer, but is there any others?

Comment: thanks all for helping me amWhy gt6989b Ross Millikan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left side is fixed and the right is increasing with $n$.  Once we find an $n$ that doesn't work, we are done because any higher $n$ will also not work.  You can check easily that $n=5$ works because $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=120 \lt 5^3$ and $3^5 \lt 3^6$.  You can then show that $n=6$ does not work as $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \gt 5^3$ and $3^6=3^6$